# cast object to specific class by string

Tags: grails, groovy

how can i dynamically cast oject to a specific class which is given as a string. e.g.

```
def a = (ClassA) testService.getObject(xmlString)
```

i would like to do something like this

```
(grailsApplication.getClassForName(classString)) testService.getObject(xmlString)
```

but the groovy compiler does not like this way of cast operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do

```
Class myClass = grailsApplication.getClassForName(classString)
myClass.cast testService.getObject(xmlString)
```

but I'm not sure how `groovy` this way is - it's really just Java way..